# jQuery 1.9.1 UI bounceslide animation not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, effect

I have tried many times to keep the bounceslide effect working in the accordion but I failed. Can someone till me what is my problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>accordion 2</title>
```

I took the below scripts from the jquery website as of today August 1, 2013.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="java/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/new/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/new/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        animated: "bounceslide"
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">Accordion Header 1</a></h3>
<div>
    xxxxxxx
</div>
<h3><a href="#">Accordion Header 2</a></h3>
<div>
    lsadjf lksj dflj slkjf lksdf 
</div>
<h3><a href="#">Accordion Header 3</a></h3>
<div>
    lkjd flksj flkj lskdjf oeijro lv,mncvpef
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your javascript references. it should be

```
type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
```